# BrowserCache Removal Not working

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, browser-cache

```
/**
 * 
 */


public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (!httpReq.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpReq.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            httpRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            httpRes.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            httpRes.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

But it is not working, I still can get pages while pressing the forward and back buttons.
Please help.I have already cleared all the exsisting cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not purposefully throw exceptions during filter's `init()` and `destroy()`. If the `init()` throws an exception, then the filter is not placed in service and some servers will even completely abort the deploy of the webapp.

They should do *nothing* if you have nothing to implement there.

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // NOOP.
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // NOOP.
}
```

You also need to make sure that the filter is mapped on the proper URL pattern or servlet name. Easiest is to put a `@WebFilter("Faces Servlet")` on the class wherein `Faces Servlet` is the exact servlet name of the `FacesServlet` entry as you have in `web.xml`.